# QuirksMode & JavaScript Implementation

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, quirks-mode

I would like to ask if Internet Explorer in QuirksMode has a different JavaScript implementation than IE in a normal mode (when doctype is correctly defined).

Is it possible that a JavaScript code will behave in a different way in QuirksMode and in normal IE mode?

Comment: Do you mean Javascript code itself or the HTML DOM, these are often incorrectly confused?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yep**.

One of the most noticeable differences is that in quirks mode, BODY (document.body) is considered to be **root element**, whereas in standard mode (and the way it's meant to be) - root element is HTML (document.documentElement).

This, for example, affects the way **viewport dimensions** are usually calculated; in standard mode, one would use `document.documentElement.clientHeight`, while in quirks - `document.body.clientHeight` - to get height of a viewport.

Detecting this behavior is easy - `document.documentElement.clientHeight == 0` - would tell us that `documentElement` is **not the root element**, and that body should be used instead.

And of course other usual quirks mode discrepancies, such as **assigning unitless CSS values**, result in a different outcome. When in quirks, such values are traditionally assigned successfully, whereas in standards mode - they are ignored.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that these are differences in the Document Object Model. The JavaScript implementation remains identical whether in quirks mode, strict mode, or being used in some non-browser context.

Comment: @NickFlitz Yes, of course. It would be weird if quirks mode affected core language implementation :) (although with IE - you never know...)

Answer (score 6):

JavaScript should not behave differently; however, the DOM objects that JavaScript operates on may have different behaviors.

Answer (score 3):

It certainly does in Internet Explorer 8 where full standards mode no longer gets `<a name="foo">` when asked `document.getElementById('foo')` and where (IIRC) `setAttribute` and friends are fixed.

Comment: That's a DOM difference, not a JavaScript difference.