# HTTP Doctype header issue causes problems in IE7?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-7, doctype

We've built a javascript based widget that our client has embedded in their website.  They claim it doesn't work on their site in IE7, and that the problem is the difference in doctype headers at the top of their pages:

**Ours:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

**Theirs:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

Is there any difference in these two headers, and how they would effect performance in IE7?

Thanks-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second doctype will trigger Quirks mode in IE. In this mode it emulates a number of bugs from IE 5.x so that it can be compatible with 199x era websites.

This has a wide range of effects and includes such things as getting the meaning of `width` in CSS wrong (fixed from IE6 onwards but only in standards mode) and getting `setAttribute` wrong (fixed from IE8 onwards, but only in standards mode).

Comment: This seems to be it.  The specific issue ended up being that an absolutely positioned div with style="left:0px;right:0px" ended up collapsing to nothing, and the fix was to specify an explicit width.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how it is broken. JS doesn't care about the DOCTYPE, but the HTML of the widget might. There are differences but it's far more likely that the problem is quirks mode vs standards mode.

Here is a [chart](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/#handling) of which DOCTYPEs trigger which modes in various browsers

Comment: Precisely, the doctype can trigger quirks or standard mode. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode

Comment: I believe that either DOCTYPE should trigger standards mode, and then the page is probably breaking standards

Comment: JS **does** care about quirks/standards mode, and HTML 4.01 Transitional with no URI triggers quirks mode.

Comment: In what way does JS care about quirks vs standards mode? To JS it is all parsed DOM.

Comment: Different bugs are exposed in the JS DOM API depending on mode. (I wouldn't be surprised if there were core JS differences too, but I don't know of any off the top of my head)

Comment: The changes are to DOM and rendering, not JS. The JS engine is the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503843/quirksmode-javascript-implementation

Comment: Switching `setAttribute` between broken and standard has nothing to do with rendering, not does the change in `getElementById('foo')` returning `<a name='foo'>...</a>`.

Comment: @Rob- looks like the second header was triggering quirks mode.  Thank you for the chart- very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

IE has been a huge culprit for having problems when doctypes arent set properly or arent showing up properly. I havent seen ie 7 doing it that often, but i know IE 6 was terrible. Are you able to declare what the doctype is?

Comment: We can't touch the doctype as it is the client's site, and we are just delivering a widget.  Thanks.